# How to connect this 5 pin audio jack?

Tags: audio, pins, stereo

I have this 5 pin 3.5mm Stereo Jack Socket, and I don't know what pin is the left, right and the ground.

[image]

Can anyone make arrows on this picture showing every pin label??

Sorry just a newbie :/

Comment: 1) Get the datasheet or  2) Get a mutimeter and a connector and map the pin out yourself. 3) The EE.SE community doesn't answer questions about components themselves. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Please read the manual

Comment: I stick a plug in and see what makes and what breaks.

Comment: @laptop2d  
I told you, I'm not a pro. if I don't ask it here, where would I ?

Comment: This isn't a great site for starters, sparkfun, hackaday and edaboard amongst others have more of the format you are looking for.

Comment: @laptop2d   I don't know those sites, it's not a big deal asking, what would happen if I did asked and got answers ? isn't this the main purpose of this site, helping each other ? don't be harsh on me :D

Comment: I'm not trying to be harsh, but I'm just saying that it would be good if you read up on how to write questions on this site. Usually questions like this get closed, which isn't a bad thing, it just means people can't answer. You really ought to google sparkfun and hackaday they are good resources for beginners.

Comment: @laptop2d 
that's would be correct if I have already known those sites, but I did not know those sites until you told me, anyway, I found my answer here, I'm glad that there still people who want to help, regardless on the situation, I would thank every last one of 'em including you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Sleeve (pin 1) is ground, right? But how can one tell what's left and what's right from the diagrams?

Comment: yeah, I think it is, 
I'm gonna use the 1,3 and 5 pins as ground, left and right respectively

Comment: like this one 
https://robrobinette.com/images/Audio/TRS_Pinout.jpg

Comment: @Ricardo: You can't tell which is what from that. What if it's not being used for audio at all?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Right. But from the OP, we can sort of tell its used for audio (it mentions left and right). I was hoping for a standard when it's used for audio. From what I can find, tip is left. So, pin 5 is left, pin 3 is right, pin 1 is ground, and pins 2 and 4 are the respective connection sensors for each channel.

Comment: @Ricardo
I think you are right !!
that's what I figured out !

Comment: @user2030409  not quite to your first comment, 1 ground (sleeve), left 'tip' (5) and right 'ring' 3, yes to the second diagram (standard connection). To Ricardo, yes, thank you. I always consider the answer from the OP point of view.